# What does it mean? (how much memory can be accessed by 32bit processor)?

Tags: memory, 32-bit

Helo, I would like to ask, what does it mean, that processor can access 
theoretical 2^32 GB of memory? Does it mean, that there are 2^32 addresses with some instructions in the memory or the instructions itself needs the memory (the data - ones and zeros) ?

And additional question is, how big can by theoretial virtual memory? I always found only recommendations about the virtual memory size, but I would like to know the possible number (theoretical on 32bit machine)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

32b CPU can address 2^32 addresses. RAM in your computer has 1 byte per address. So CPU can address 2^32 bytes of data.

As for the virtual memory: 
4 Gigs of additional virutal memory, default settings is 2 gigs for system and 2 gigs for process

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366912(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Maybe I get it. It means i have 2^32 Bytes? As you wrote I have 2^32 addresses and each address is 8 bits? So I have 4 294 967 296 Bytes of data? How I can get the magical 4GB of RAM? Can you please tell me how to convert it?

Comment: kilo, mega, giga is in this case multiplication by 1024 (2^10), not 1000. so 4294967296/1024/1024/1024 = 4